# WPF: While moving user control with images data context is lost

Tags: wpf, devexpress-wpf

1) Don't move anything - everything works fine:

[image]

2) Move user control with images - the images disappeared:

[image]

3) When I move user control with images back to original place - the images are there that is everything works fine again.

The user control with images that I moved was placed inside another user control. The code looks as following:

1) The user control with images:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GCE.Eam.Modules.VisualCheckAnalysis.SelectedEventImageList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GCE.Eam.Modules.VisualCheckAnalysis"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:PathToFileConverter x:Key="PathToFileConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <ListView Grid.Row="0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEventPhotoList}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEventPhoto}"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Name="SelectedListView">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxe:ImageEdit Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PathToFileConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True"
                                       ShowBorder="False">
                            <dxe:ImageEdit.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                                              Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseDoubleClickUpperRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
                            </dxe:ImageEdit.InputBindings>
                        </dxe:ImageEdit>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="2"
                      Background="Gainsboro" ResizeDirection="Auto"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView
                      ItemsSource="{Binding MatchingEventPhotoList}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMatchingEventPhoto}"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Name="MatchingListView">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#00000000"/>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxe:ImageEdit Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PathToFileConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True"
                                       ShowBorder="False">
                            <dxe:ImageEdit.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
                                              Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseDoubleClickLowerRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
                            </dxe:ImageEdit.InputBindings>
                        </dxe:ImageEdit>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

2) The user control that contains user control with images:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GCE.Eam.Modules.VisualCheckAnalysis.VisualCheckAnalyzerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:visualCheckAnalysis="clr-namespace:GCE.Eam.Modules.VisualCheckAnalysis"
             xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
             xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
             xmlns:dxr="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/ribbon"
             xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
             xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking" 
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:GCE.AppFramework.Behaviors;assembly=GCE.AppFramework"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance visualCheckAnalysis:VisualCheckAnalyzerViewModel}"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <dxb:BarManager>
        <dxb:BarManager.Items>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="Refresh" Content="Пересчитать"
                               Hint="Обновить окно режима анализа ВИК"
                               ShowKeyGesture="False"
                               Glyph="Images/Recalculate_16.png"
                               LargeGlyph="Images/Recalculate_32.png"
                               Command="{Binding RecalculateCommand}"
                               KeyGesture="F5"
                               />

            <dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="MatchRadiusEdit"
                                             EditWidth="60" ToolTip="{Binding DefaultMatchRadiusTooltip}"
                             Content="Rср" EditValue="{Binding MatchRadius}" >
                <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:SpinEditSettings MaskType="Numeric" IsFloatValue="True"
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                          MinValue="{Binding MinRadius, Mode=OneWay}"
                                          MaxValue="{Binding MaxRadius, Mode=OneWay}"
                                          Increment="{Binding Increment, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
            </dxb:BarEditItem>

            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="AddBaseTab" Content="В закладку"
                               Hint="Открыть закладку для выделенного объекта"
                               Glyph="Images/ToTab_16.png" LargeGlyph="Images/ToTab_32.png"
                               Command="{Binding  ActivateBaseEvent}" />

            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="AddMatchingTab" Content="В закладку"
                               Hint="Открыть закладку для выделенного объекта"
                               Glyph="Images/ToTab_16.png" LargeGlyph="Images/ToTab_32.png"
                               Command="{Binding  ActivateMatchingEvent}" />

        </dxb:BarManager.Items>


        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <dxr:RibbonControl x:Name="RibbonControl" Grid.Row="0" RibbonStyle="Office2010"
                               PageCategoryAlignment="Left" ToolbarShowCustomizationButton="False"
                               ShowApplicationButton="False" ToolbarShowMode="Hide">

                <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviors:NoContextMenuDxRibbonBehavior/>
                </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>

                <dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
                    <dxr:RibbonPage x:Name="MainPage" Caption="Главная">
                        <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="Операции" MergeOrder="{x:Static visualCheckAnalysis:VisualCheckAnalysisModule.ModuleSortHint}">
                            <dxb:BarEditItemLink BarItemName="MatchRadiusEdit"/>
                            <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="Refresh" />
                        </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                    </dxr:RibbonPage>
                </dxr:RibbonDefaultPageCategory>
            </dxr:RibbonControl>

            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                <dxlc:LayoutControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <dxlc:LayoutGroup VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Orientation="Vertical"
                                      dxlc:LayoutControl.AllowVerticalSizing="True"
                                      Width="Auto">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Обслед. для сопоставления: "/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding BaseInspectionName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </TextBlock>

                            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                                <visualCheckAnalysis:SelectedEventsList/>
                                <dxb:BarManager.DXContextMenu>
                                    <dxb:PopupMenu x:Name="PopupMenu">
                                        <dxb:PopupMenu.ItemLinks>
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="AddBaseTab" UserGlyphSize="Small"/>
                                        </dxb:PopupMenu.ItemLinks>
                                    </dxb:PopupMenu>
                                </dxb:BarManager.DXContextMenu>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutGroup VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Orientation="Vertical"
                                      dxlc:LayoutControl.AllowVerticalSizing="True"
                                      Width="Auto">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <visualCheckAnalysis:InspectionList Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                                <visualCheckAnalysis:MatchingEventList/>
                                <dxb:BarManager.DXContextMenu>
                                    <dxb:PopupMenu x:Name="MatchedPopupMenu">
                                        <dxb:PopupMenu.ItemLinks>
                                            <dxb:BarButtonItemLink BarItemName="AddMatchingTab" UserGlyphSize="Small"/>
                                        </dxb:PopupMenu.ItemLinks>
                                    </dxb:PopupMenu>
                                </dxb:BarManager.DXContextMenu>
                            </Border>

                        </Grid>
                    </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                    <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                        <dxdo:DocumentGroup AllowDrag="True" AllowFloat="True" AllowMove="True"
                                            ShowTabForSinglePage="True" ClosePageButtonShowMode="InAllTabPageHeaders">
                            <dxdo:DocumentPanel ShowCaption="True" Caption="Картинки для сопоставления" ShowCaptionImage="True"
                                                CaptionImage="pack://application:,,,/GCE.Eam.OilAndGasIndustry;component/Images/Photo_16.png"
                                                ToolTip="Картинки для сопоставления">
                                <visualCheckAnalysis:SelectedEventImageList/>
                            </dxdo:DocumentPanel>
                        </dxdo:DocumentGroup>
                    </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
                </dxlc:LayoutControl>
            </Border>
            <dxr:RibbonStatusBarControl Grid.Row="2">
            </dxr:RibbonStatusBarControl>
        </Grid>
    </dxb:BarManager>
</UserControl>
```

Where visualCheckAnalysis:SelectedEventImageList is user control with images.

As you can see I use DevExpress docking controls.

It seems to me that I loose data context when move user control with images, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

UPDATE:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEventPhotoList}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEventPhoto}"
            ...
```

Comment: Try to set the explicitly set the DataContext of the SelectedEventImageList control to an instance of the class with the SelectedEventPhotoList and SelectedEventPhoto properties. If the DataContext is inherited from the parent window the bindings will no longer work when the DocumentGroup is floating because then it is no longer a visual child of the window.

Comment: You mean to set DataContext explicitly in XAML?

Comment: For example, yes.

Comment: I've updated the original post with full XAML code of user control that contains user control with images. That outer user control contains all together 4 parts (user controls) of UI: visualCheckAnalysis:SelectedEventsList, visualCheckAnalysis:InspectionList, visualCheckAnalysis:MatchingEventList, visualCheckAnalysis:SelectedEventImageList. The specific here is that the last visualCheckAnalysis:SelectedEventImageList user control could be moved out of context of outer user control and because of that it looses its data context.

Comment: Please, take a look at "UPDATE" section in original post to see what I did. It doesn't work without moving now. I'm not sure if you meant on that.

Comment: Where is the SelectedEventPhotoList property defined and how do you set the DataContext of the VisualCheckAnalyzerView? Your issue is not reproducible. You should read this and edit your question accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The SelectedEventPhotoList property is defined in VisualCheckAnalyzerViewModel. And DataContext for VisualCheckAnalyzerView is set in DataTemplates.xaml file in this way: <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:GCE.Eam.Modules.VisualCheckAnalysis">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:VisualCheckAnalyzerViewModel}">
        <viewModels:VisualCheckAnalyzerView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

Comment: And DataTemplates.xaml is used in VisualCheckAnalysisModule module (Prism) in this way: private static readonly Uri _dataTemplatesUri = new Uri("/GCE.Eam.Modules.VisualCheckAnalysis;component/DataTemplates.xaml", UriKind.Relative); etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to handle the `Loaded` event for the `SelectedEventImageList` control and explicitly set its `DataContext`.

Something like this:

```
<visualCheckAnalysis:SelectedEventImageList Loaded="Control_Loaded" />
```

---

```
private bool _isLoaded;
private void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isLoaded)
    {
        SelectedEventImageList ctrl = sender as SelectedEventImageList;
        ctrl.DataContext = this.DataContext;
        _isLoaded = true;
    }
}
```